# Use ComboBox input to find itself in the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am new to VBA and UserForms.

I have a ComboBox where the user will enter a unique Sales Order # (SalesOrder). I want my form to take this input and find it in the workbook and then update the status with the user's inputs in later ComboBoxes (CommentBox & OrderStatus). The issue I am facing is the actual code to find the Sales Order # in the workbook. I've tried what is seen below in several different variations.

If I replace all the ComboBox inputs with the actual inputs as a string, the code runs fine in a module.

Ideally, the code will loop through the sheet array finding all the lines with the Sales Order # and apply the inputs to the row.

```
Sub AddDataToList()

    Dim shtarray As Variant, shtname As Variant
    Dim Data As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim Strg As String

shtarray = Array("EMAUX", "Irene", "Cassandra", "Patricia", "EMREL", "Maria", "Jason", "Peedie", "MICRO", "PARTS", "NAVY", "DELTA")

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

    For Each shtname In shtarray
        Set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wbk.Worksheets(shtname)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not (ws Is Nothing) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(StatusUpdateForm.SalesOrder.Text).Offset(0, 17).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = CommentBox.Text
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = OrderStatus.Text
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox SalesOrder.Value & "was updated."

End Sub
```

Thank you for the assistance!

More Information ***
Below is the code for the Update command button. This is a standard two button system, one updates the records and the other cancels the form.

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
    
    If Not EverythingFilledIn Then Exit Sub
    
    Me.Hide
    
    AddDataToList
    
    Unload Me
    
End Sub
```

And code for the EverthingFilledIn

```
Private Function EverythingFilledIn() As Boolean

    Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
    Dim AnythingMissing As Boolean
    
    EverthingFilledIn = True
    AnythingMissing = False
    
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.TextBox Or TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
            If ctl.Value = "" Then
                ctl.BackColor = rgbPink
                Controls(ctl.Name & "Label").ForeColor = rgbRed
                If Not AnythingMissing Then ctl.SetFocus
                AnythingMissing = True
                EverythingFilledIn = False
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
End Function
```

Comment: Why is your loop looking through sheets which may not exist?

Comment: Either way your loop should reference `ws` not the activesheet or cell (which never change) and check you've found something first to avoid errors.

Comment: Hi SJR, the sheets do exist in the Workbook. There is a table where external data is pulled from another workbook and I don't want the code to try and update the table (if that's even possible). So I created an array to only target certain sheets.

Comment: So why do you check that `ws` isn't `Nothing` if you know it exists?

Comment: That's how it was written in another form. If it's not needed then I can take it out, but it didn't affect the code when I ran this with all strings.

Comment: No I don't think it would cause your problem, it's just not necessary. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (my first comment notwithstanding):

```
Sub AddDataToList()

Dim shtarray As Variant, shtname As Variant
Dim Data As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim Strg As String
Dim r As Range

shtarray = Array("EMAUX", "Irene", "Cassandra", "Patricia", "EMREL", "Maria", "Jason", "Peedie", "MICRO", "PARTS", "NAVY", "DELTA")

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

For Each shtname In shtarray
    Set ws = wbk.Worksheets(shtname)
    Set r = ws.Cells.Find(StatusUpdateForm.SalesOrder.Text) 'better to specify all parameters
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
         r.Offset(0, 17).Value = CommentBox.Text
         r.Offset(0, 2).Value = OrderStatus.Text
    End If
Next

MsgBox SalesOrder.Value & "was updated."

End Sub
```

There is [no need to select things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Hi, I've made the updates as shown but when I click the Update command button, nothing happens. I'm not sure what the issue is, but I do appreciate your input for cleaning up the selections.

Comment: I've provided the code I use for the Update and Cancel command buttons above.

Comment: If nothing happens probably the text is not found.

Comment: The ComboBox is populated by a list from the first sheet in the array. I've been testing this by taking a Sales Order # that is found on multiple sheets in the array and trying to update it with one form entry. When I click update, nothing happens and the form remains open and populated.

Comment: You need to step through the code to see what's going on, I have no way of knowing what is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to step through a form. I can do this in a module but I don't have any knowledge of this when inputs are required by the user.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint at the start and then you can step through each line when the code is interrupted.

Comment: So I half solved the issue. I had an extra "End If" in the first set of code. I can now update the Sales Order in my workbook. The next issue is something in the EverythingFilledIn subroutine. I'll have to play around with that tomorrow. Thanks again SJR!